# I used Shapeshift to transfer BTC to Monero about 18 hours ago and it is still not showing in GUI wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I used Shapeshift to transfer BTC to Monero about 18 hours ago and it is still not showing in GUI wallet?
I can see it has been sent on the blockchain on shapeshift
Funds have been returned to BTC markets exchange
I tried updated Wallet to recent update (mac) 
Its does say status disconnected? But it seems to connect to Daemon and show my old balance. Should I just wait longer, is +18 hours a normal time for the blocks to sync?
I am not that tech so hoping its just time. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use that guide ^

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you have the latest version of the Monero wallet 0.11.1.0. The sync will stop if you have an older version.